# Training ELMO on TPU for generating embedding from custom dataset

Tags: tensorflow, embedding, tpu, elmo

Is it possible training ELMO model from scratch on tpu instead of gpu?
i want to generate Turkish elmo embedding from custom large corpus.

Comment: Yes. Is possible with the right model and dataset.

Comment: thanks. i have never used tpu before. i have Turkish corpus about 40gb size. i want to use this elmo model (https://github.com/allenai/bilm-tf) . i follow steps for installation enviroment and creating vocab. how can i make configuration model for use on tpu?